# How do you get skype to read other text in a message vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, skype, skype4com

I was wondering if there is an easy way to load text from a command from skype using the SKYPE4COMLib.dll API Supported file. I am trying to get the bot to trigger ! Then  - Is there an easy way to have it copy it to a textbox?
Thanks!
-Dom

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example:

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Dim valid As Boolean = False
Dim WithEvents sBot As New Skype

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sBot.Attach(7, False)
End Sub

Private _WaitHandle_FirstThreadDone As New System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

Private Sub sBot_MessageStatus(pMessage As ChatMessage, Status As TChatMessageStatus) Handles sBot.MessageStatus
    If Status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived Or Status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent Then

        Dim Msg As String = pMessage.Body
        Dim c As Chat = pMessage.Chat

        If Msg.StartsWith("!hello") Then
            c.SendMessage("Hello sir!")
```

Comment: This works perfectly for users, however, it doesn't detect group chat messages and therefore doesn't reply to them as well. Is there another way to do it?